# How to insert an Excel file to a column with varbinary type into an SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, file, varbinarymax

I have a table: Formats

with columns:

FileName,Document_binary,Format,UsedBy,Date and Id

Document column is VARBINARY(MAX).

There are some already loaded documents with names like: 0x504b34xxxx and so on, all of these are excel files that users can download from a site.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have this file formar, the file itself stored in the database for when a user needs the file go get it from the system as a download. Not the data contained in it but the file itself.

I need to do it manually without any interface.

I tried this below with no luck:

```
    INSERT INTO Formats
    (FileName, Document_binary,Format,UploadUser,UploadDateTime,Id)

    values

    ('Case_Project', * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\jhon\Desktop\Worksheet 
     in 6W2H update Jul2018 formato std.xlsx'), 
     'Template','jhon.doe',NOW,22)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * INTO Formats (FileName, Document_binary,Format,UploadUser,UploadDateTime,Id)
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Users\jhon\Desktop\Worksheet_in_6W2H_update_Jul2018_formato_std.xlsx; HDR=YES; IMEX=1','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');
```

Keep the file name without space.

Comment: Thank you Looking for something different.